# Canvas не рисует, находясь в display: none блоке

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

У меня есть модальное окно:

```
    <div class="modal" id="last" style="display: none">
     <canvas id="gg" width="372px" height="144px"/>
    </div>
```

Если я запущу его, канвас будет пустым. Но стоит только убрать style="display: none", как канвас рисует, в общем мне нужно чтобы канвас рисовался в моем модальном окне.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не присвоить нужное значение display в JS'e, перед отрисовкой на канве?

Comment: В том то и дело) Что код вызывающий мое модальное окно, ставит display "" )))

Answer (score 1):

Присвой `display:block`. А вообще, с пустой строкой должно тоже работать.

Answer (score -1):

так работает

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="display: none" >
```

Comment: приведённый код из работающего проекта

Comment: Что за код? Для чего он мне? (p.s. минусы ставил не я)

Comment: @LiveD если б у тебя в вопросе было сказано,- что div это "модальное окно", я б и не стал постить. (а про минусы к минусующим)

Comment: @LiveD  если у тебя в div только convas, то от div можно избавиться и сделать canvas "модальным"

Comment: Печаль, но там не только канвас, там еще парочка нужных дивов)

Comment: @LiveD ну если вообще не будет получаться  - можно canvas в конце body разместить в него вписать картинку и потом переместить в див

Comment: Все еще жду решений.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24923/discussion-between-lived-and-).

Comment: @Вадим, может быть, ставят минусы и подчищают за вами разные люди?

Comment: @Nofate то что подчищают я не против, меня бесит минусование без указания причины, кто-то решил что я не прав и заминусовал, а на каком основании он так решил?